# Unable to locate element using selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to do some automation testing on a website called http://elegalix.allahabadhighcourt.in. I am using the following python code to click a button called "Advanced" on the above website:

Code#

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get('http://elegalix.allahabadhighcourt.in')
driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Advanced']").click()
```

Error#

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //input[@value='Advanced']
```

P.S I am a newbie to python programming. I have tried different variations of xpath and have tried to use other find_element_by methods but none seems to work on this website...I m experiencing similar error on Firefox browser as well...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because the element you are looking for is inside a frame, switch to the frame first and then search for the element

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get('http://elegalix.allahabadhighcourt.in')
driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name('sidebarmenu'))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Advanced']").click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Thank-you so much. Could you suggest some good resource for learning python for web-automation using selenium...I have decent experience with c/c++ but no HTML/CSS knowledge

Comment: https://youtu.be/l15ZJAbxCL8, this is a wonderful presentation and insight to how to use selenium and python for web automation. This is more geared towards testing but should help you get started

Answer (score 1):

I faced with this issue and the problem about the window size. Because when window size is small, objects place has changed so i use `driver.maximize_window()` and then i use `driver.find()` method it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

After the command to open the link add this:

```
driver.maximize_window()
```