# Unable to locate element in Python Selenium webdriver find_element_by_xpath

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, webdriver

i'm trying to click the "download Results" button on [this website](https://www.cms.gov/apps/physician-fee-schedule/search/search-results.aspx?Y=0&T=4&HT=2&CT=3&H1=74750&H2=74800&M=5)  .

i'm using below python code to click this button

```
from selenium import webdriver
chromedriver_path = 'E:/software/python/chromedriver'
url = 'https://www.cms.gov/apps/physician-fee-schedule/search/search-results.aspx?Y=0&T=4&HT=2&CT=3&H1=74750&H2=74800&M=5'
driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path )
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Download Results"]').click()
```

i'm getting below error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//frame[@name="aspnetForm"]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=83.0.4103.116)
```

i'm thinking if the button is within a iframe but how do I find out the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you out: [Unable to locate element using selenium webdriver in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44661187/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python/44661357)

Try and switch to the frame first, and then search for the element.

Answer (score 0):

i realized that there's a agreement page that i need to click 'Agree' button first.
i didn't see this in browser because i already clicked 'Agree' weeks ago. but in webdriver, i need to click that each time.

Answer (score 0):

Just after the URL opens, a page comes up asking you to agree the terms. You need to click on that `Agree` first. Since it is possible that once clicking on the `Agree` button, it won't come again if you accepted it on default browser. So just be sure with code, you can first check the presence of the agree button first.

This kind of function you may make to check presence:

```
def elementPresent(locatorType, locator):
    #present = true
    #not present = false
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    try:
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((locatorType, locator)))
    except Exception:
        return False
    return True
```

And then using if condition you may proceed further like:

```
if(elementPresent("xpath", "//a[@title='Accept']/span")):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='Accept']/span").click()
```

and then you may click on the element you want, there is no frame that is required to be switched to.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title = 'Download Results']/span").click()
```

Just extract the element and click on it and your required file will be downloaded.